# How to restrict specific characters in TinyMce?

Tags: extjs, tinymce

I am using TinyMce editor in Ext-Js 4.1 and I need to restrict user to some specific characters in editor.

I tried maskRe but it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Of course maskRe won't work becasue tinymce is not using a textarea but a contenteditable iframe. I suggest you write a small function to cleanup the editor code from time to time or to block their input.

Comment: I use maskRe where TinyMce extend Ext.form.field.TextArea, Why it not also work over there?

Comment: tinymce is not a textarea. maskRe  will only work on the tinymce source element (in your case a textarea) but the editor content gets written back to that field - probably without getting cleaned up.

Comment: ok, I got it.so can I use replace function on change callback event of editor?

Comment: depending on your aim, i might be sufficient to remove those other characters just before form submit (http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3:event.tinymce.Editor.onSubmit). you may also want to check for other editor events (see the list on the right)